# How prevent extra page and text running off bottom of page in Latex?

Tags: blank-page

I am struggling trying to build a Latex document  using the report document class in TexMaker outputting to PDF on a Debian system.  My second chapter inserts a blank page between it and the beginning of the next chapter, and the first page of the following chapter runs off the end of the page, totally obscuring the page number.

I have searched stack overflow on the blank page issue and tried the openany and onside document class options without any success.

Any suggestions at all would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a minimum working example of the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside,openany]{report}

\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1 Title}

\section{1.1 Title}

\section{1.2 Title}

\section{1.3 Title}

\section{1.4 Title}

\section{1.5 Title}

\section{1.6 Title}

\section{1.7 Title}

\chapter{Chapter 2 Title}

\section{2.1 Title}

\section{2.2 Title}

\section{2.3 Title}

\subsection{2.3.1 Title}

\subsection{2.3.1 Title}

\subsection{2.3.1 Title}

\subsection{2.3.1 Title}

\subsection{2.3.1 Title}

\subsection{2.3.1 Title}

\subsection{2.3.1 Title}

\subsection{2.3.1 Title}

\subsection{2.3.1 Title}

\subsection{2.3.1 Title}

\subsection{2.3.1 Title}

\section{2.4 Title}

\section{2.5 Title}

\section{2.6 Title}

\section{2.7 Title}

\section{2.8 Title}

\section{2.9 Title}

\section{2.10 Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to provide us with some form of code to analyse the problem. Specifically, a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem. There may be many reasons why you're experiencing the troubles you're working with, so a conclusive answer would require something that can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I added a minimal working example as requested.

Comment: Your MWE does exhibit the problem you describe, but it goes away if you add any text to each section/subsection. Do you have a more reasonable example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Dan - thanks very much for the effort in figuring out you can make it work by adding some text! While I changed the text in my MWE from the original to shrink it down, even my original did not have any text in each section yet.  My intent was to build a template for a report that just had the chapter, section and subsections in it rather than a complete document.  Is there a better way to build a template? If not I can certainly add a minimum amount of text to each section in the template as a workaround.

Comment: @Dan Do you want to turn your comment into an answer?